# How to use servlet in slim3 with GWT to upload BlobStore

Tags: google-app-engine

i have project similar to `http://ikaisays.com/2010/09/08/gwt-blobstore-the-new-high-performance-image-serving-api-and-cute-dogs-on-office-chairs/`, It use BlobStore to store image on google app engine.
But I work with slim3 freamwork.

follow the tutorial i create Fileupload form and Servlet. When i submit the form, note that it don't call to Servlet. I thing may be i don't know config the app.

As i do :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>daTotNghiep.server.UploadServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/upload</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

// get blobStore URL to upload, and set return value to uploadForm.Action(string)

```
public String getBlobstoreUploadUrl() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    return blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload");
}
```

With 2 config at that , Sure uploadForm.submit() will call to servlet ?

Full tutorial source : `http://github.com/ikai/gwt-gae-image-gallery`

Answer (score 1):

> Slim3 Controller is a thin framework of Servlet. Slim3 can find a controller that is like Servlet from the path automatically, so you don't need the manual configuration. Due to HOT reloading, when you change the source code, you can see the result on your browser without restarting web application.

so instant use servlet in Slim3 we use Controller. It has work for me

Answer (score 0):

try this one if u go like that

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Upload</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>gwtwithslim.server.service.Upload</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Serve</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>gwtwithslim.server.service.Serve</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Upload</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service.s3gwt/upload/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Serve</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service.s3gwt/serve/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```